# How can I compare the MLE by standard error?

Tags: maximum-likelihood, standard-deviation, likelihood, gumbel-distribution

In the paper [Extreme value theory based on the r largest annual events](https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwj8jfTRm5_7AhXAl2oFHdC1DQoQFnoECAsQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.sciencedirect.com%2Fscience%2Farticle%2Fpii%2F0022169486900041%2Fpdf%3Fmd5%3Daee2c7bf861feb4509bfdc92d991cfdc%26pid%3D1-s2.0-0022169486900041-main.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3dsl2u805Ps5YHN_AYqbgl)
 (page 32), the idea is that he wants to fit the Gumbel distribution using a dataset. In this dataset, we have the largest ten values. He wants to compare if we will get a better estimate of the parameters in Gumbel using the ten largest values than only one annual maximal. He got the maximal likelihood estimators of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in Gumbel (consistency and asymptotic normal).

***Question:*** The authors want to compare which is the better estimate of the estimated quantity under different $r. $
How can I get this conclusion by standard error?

---

For example, for MLE of $\alpha$, why is $r=5$  better than $r=1?$ Since we know that
$$
\rm MSE=Bias^2+Variance,
$$
do not we also need the bias is smaller?

It seems that MLE are consistent, so is the bias  asymptotically small?

Comment: What does "$r$" represent?

Comment: I have attached a link to the paper. The article wants to fit the Gumbel distribution, r is r largest order statistics. He wants to compare the fit of a maximum (r=1), and the first r maximums of the MLE which is better.

Comment: Where did you obtain the image of the table?  It's not in that paper given in the link.

Comment: @JimB Sorry, I copied the wrong paper. I have fixed it. On the page 32, the author compared the model for $\mu$ is linear.

Comment: One would expect that using more information to estimate a distribution is better than less information.  So using the largest 5 order statistics would be expected to have smaller standard errors for the parameters than only using the maximum (the largest order statistic).  The author gives an estimate of the magnitude of that effect as summarized by the standard errors.  You should explicitly state that $r$ is the number of largest order statistics used in the estimation of the distribution parameters.  And in your last comment introducing another undefined term ($\mu$) doesn't help.

Comment: @JimB Thanks! But I think we need to compare the moment square error for these two estimators for $r=1$ and $r=5$. That is because of MSE=bias^2+variance. If we only have variance is smaller, can we $r=5$ is better than $r=1$?

Comment: Because the article is behind a paywall, you probably won't get as much help until you fully explain the issues in your question.  But I could be wrong.

Comment: @JimB The idea is that he wants to fit the Gumbel distribution using a dataset. In this dataset, we have the largest ten values. He wants to compare if we will get a better estimate of the parameters in Gumbel using the ten largest values than only one annual maximal. He got the maximal likelihood estimators of $\mu$ and $\sigma$ in Gumbel (consistency and asymptotic normal). Dose it make sense?

Comment: @JimB I edited the link to that paper. Maybe you can open it in a pdf file now?

Comment: Yes, that makes sense.  I'm only suggesting that more details be given in the question rather than in comments.  And I could access the article previously through my work.  I was concerned for others.

Comment: The article is still behind a pay wall. Could you post the final results. Which joint distribution do they fit and by which method?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Sure, I added the joint distribution of the model. The final results is that table comparing MLE for different values of $r$.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Dose it make sense now?

Comment: @Hermi, I think I can work with that. And they just compute jointly the MLE for the three parameters? (One thing that I find weird is the $n/N$ term, why did they add a dependency on the year $n$?)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Yes, they use the asymptotic joint distribution for fitting the data. In paper, authors thought that there is a increasing trend. Well, this is my another question. Why the author set a linear regression model for $\mu_n=\alpha+\beta(n/N)$.

Answer (score 2):

1. The question in this paper is stated in the bottom of page 28: **"Suppose we are given , not just the maximum value for each year, but the largest ten (say) values. How might we use this data to obtain better estimates than could be made with just the annual maxima?"**.
2. With $r$ being the number of largest annual values, they are ordered (descending) and assumed to be iid. This is what enables eqn (2.1).
3. They don't just use the linear trend model introduced in equation (2.4) but also a quadratic model (eqn 3.1) and two different periodic models (11 and 19 years) (eqn 2.6).
   [image: periodical trend model]
   [image: quadratic trend model]

> ***Question:*** The authors want to compare which is the better estimate of the estimated quantity under different $r. $ How can I get
> this conclusion by standard error?
>
> For example, for MLE of $\alpha$, why is $r=5$  better than $r=1?$
> Since we know that $$ \rm MSE=Bias^2+Variance, $$ do not we also need
> the bias is smaller?

You can see in the comments [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/71197/usable-estimators-for-parameters-in-gumbel-distribution) the reasons for using a biased estimator in order to get a lower MSE. Furthermore, with $r$ increasing from 1 to 5 or 10, we are bound to get a lower MSE: the $r$ observations are independent, hence the information function grows and we get a better [Cramér–Rao lower bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cram%C3%A9r%E2%80%93Rao_bound#Bound_on_the_variance_of_biased_estimators).

> Another question: for this non-stationary dataset, why did the author
> set $\mu=\mu_n?$ This seems to be very similar to the residual in
> linear regression model.

As you can see, they used different trend models. They do note just below eqn (3.3) the results obtained for the likelihood functions. You can see the comparison of the 4 models in fig. 2 where they compare the annual predicted maxima and medians. They further explain, under the summary section, that "In the Venice data, the main contribution to trend was a linear trend  from 1931 onwards" and then explain that other trends had lesser effect.

Comment: But does the method of using $r$ maxima increase the bias or not?

Comment: The use of $r$ maxima decreases the variance there's no doubt about that, but the Cramer Rao bound that you mention does not relate to the MSE, it relates to the variance. It is nice that we can reduce the variance. A constant estimator will even have zero variance. But, we also need to place it into perspective in relation to bias. Sure a biased estimator *can* be better, but *is* it better in this case?

Comment: The authors do not use MSE anywhere, their comparison is based mainly on information and covariance matrices. I seriously cannot stress enough how much the OP needs to read the whole article.

Comment: But for a biased estimator... Does a smaller SD mean a smaller MSE? What if the biased with r=1 is much smaller than the biased  with r=5?

Comment: What do you mean here "the r observations are independent, hence the information function grows and we get a better Cramér–Rao lower bound."?

Comment: @Spätzle the authors may not have mentioned MSE and showed how the estimator is better in terms of lower variance, but the question here is about the MSE and about what happens with this estimator if we also bring bias into the picture.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus However, we cannot calculate the MSE for practical problems, because we do not know the true value of the parameters. So, the authors have to retreat to the second best way to calculate the variance?

Comment: @Hermi or make simulations and see how the bias is for particular cases. (I intend to try this out, but I am actually still trying to figure out the derivation for the formula, I particularly find it interesting how the values $X_{nj}$ all contribute the same, while intuively I would expect a dependency on $j$)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Do you think that the author assume that $X_{n1}, \dots, X_{nr}$ are iid for a fix $n$? I know that  the author assumes that the separate data for different years $n$ are independent (not identical distributed).

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Because we need the daily data $Y_1,\dots, Y_n$ to be iid, then we can approximate the distribution of annual maximum by Gumbel distribution.

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Do you mean how to get the likelihood function of the $r-$largest order statistics? That is a result in this paper https://www.google.com.hk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjfnoKA_cL7AhWAm2oFHWAtBUMQFnoECAwQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.jstor.org%2Fstable%2F2286285&usg=AOvVaw2jG3wlykBBaEza7YMM4zq0.

Comment: @Hermi that equation 2.6 from the paper that you just linked to makes a lot of sense. It looks a lot like the picture [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4283180/466748): the distances/spacings between different ordered values are independent exponentially distributed variables with varying rates. (the $X_{n1}, \dots, X_{nr}$ which are cumulative sums of those differences are not independent)

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Ok. I am a little bit confused. Since there is a iid assumption in the extreme value theorem, then the asymptotic distribution of the annual maximum is the extreme value theorem. So which data do we assume here is the iid? Isn't it the daily record data?

Comment: @SextusEmpiricus Also, The authors explain that the reason for choosing r=5 instead of 10 is that r=5 ensures that $X_{n1}, \dots, X_{nr}$ are independent. In practice, a storm may come and last for several days with a sea surface maximum, and if r is too large, independence may be lost. So why do the authors need r = 5 to guarantee independence?

Comment: Bottom of p37: "The effect of a single storm may be to create several days of very high water levels; the readings taken on these days will obviously not be independent. On the other hand, high water levels measured during storms which are several weeks or months apart may be expected to be approximately independent. The distribution (2.1) assumes that the observed values $X_1, ..., X_r$ arise from $r$ separate storms, which are sufficiently far apart in time to be treated as independent". Then in p38, just above the plot, the explain why taking $r=5$ rather than 10. Just read the whole paper.